# $httpBackend mock responds with more than what I tell it to?

Tags: angularjs

I have a Jasmine test for one of my Angular services which fetches data from a server and makes it publicly accessible. The server returns JSON, just an array of objects `[{...}, {...}, ...]`.

Now I tried writing a test with a mocked out http backend:

```
var mockLibrary = [{}, {}];
beforeEach(inject(function(LibrarySvc) {
    libSvc = LibrarySvc;
}));

it('should fetch the library', function(done) {
    inject(function($httpBackend) {
        $httpBackend.expectGET('/library').respond(200, mockLibrary);

        libSvc.getLibrary()
            .then(function(response) {
                expect(_.isEqual(response, mockLibrary)).toBeTruthy();
            })
          .finally(done);

        $httpBackend.flush();
    });
});
```

The code in my service is as follows:

```
var library;
var deferred = $q.defer();

$http.get('/library')
    .then(function(data) {
        library = data;
        deferred.resolve(library);
    }, function(err) {
        deferred.reject(err);
    });
```

So, the service assigns the JSON response body of the server to an internal `library` variable and resolves the promise with it. Now when running this test, it fails, because `response` in the test is not equal to `mockLibrary`. Instead, `response` is this:

`Object{data: [Object{}, Object{}], status: 200, headers: function (c){ ... }, config: Object{method: 'GET', transformRequest: [...], transformResponse: [...], url: '/library', headers: Object{Accept: ...}}, statusText: ''}`

and what I actually wanted would now be `response.data` in the test, and `data.data` in my service logic.

**Why** does Angular do this? Is this implicitly suggesting that JSON responses from my server should always be a hash that holds the actual response data in a `data` attribute? Why would I ever want to adjust my service logic to an Angular test? Or did I miss something? The docs for $httpBackend weren't helpful on this matter.

---

Further notes: I'm using underscore.js for a deep equals check at `_.isEqual(...)`, and Jasmine 2.0 to test asynchronously (thus the `function(done)` syntax).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `.then()` for the `$http`, the first parameter won't be the data from your server.

It will be a wrapper object like you see and the data from your server will be in `.data`.

There is no different between your service and the test. You might be confused and think that the `data` parameter in your service is the data from your server, it isn't.

Therefore, yes, you have to use `response.data` in your test and `data.data` in your service. But I suggest you rename the `data` parameter in your service to `response` for consistency.

Also see: [$http documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.22/docs/api/ng/service/$http)